# UITableView header view not responding to touches on empty table

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I'm having a weird problem, which I'm sure has an easy fix/explanation, but I've spent the weekend trying without luck.

I have a custom `UIView` as my tableHeaderView, which contains two `UIButton`s. Pressing one `UIButton` or the other, changes the data inside the `UITableView` by changing the dataSource, and doing a `[tableView reloadData]`.

The problem I have is when after pressing one of the buttons, I reload the table but I have no rows (dataSource/table is empty). I can't press the other button to change the dataSource and reload the table back because It becomes unresponsive, doesn't respond to touches.

The only explanation I have is maybe `UITableView`s don't respond to touches when they are empty? But seems like a bug that the tableHeaderView doesn't respond either..

This happens both in iOS 6 and iOS 7.

PS: I'm aware I could detect the dataSource is empty before doing a reloadData and keep the data for the other dataSource, but I need to show the button as pressed and show a message under it when is empty, so that doesn't help me.

This is how I create the Table header view, and assign it to the tableView.

```
self.tableCustomHeader = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 48)];
self.tableCustomHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

// Configure Header
self.rankingBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
self.rankingBtn.frame = CGRectMake(3, 4, 157, 40);
self.rankingBtn.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
self.rankingBtn.adjustsImageWhenDisabled = NO;
[self.rankingBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"amigos_boton_ranking_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.rankingBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"amigos_boton_ranking_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
[self.rankingBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"amigos_boton_ranking_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.rankingBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(fetchRanking:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

if (self.listType == FriendsListTypeRanking) {
    self.alfabeticBtn.enabled = NO;
}

self.alfabeticBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
self.alfabeticBtn.frame = CGRectMake(160, 4, 157, 40);
self.alfabeticBtn.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
self.alfabeticBtn.adjustsImageWhenDisabled = NO;
[self.alfabeticBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"amigos_boton_alfabetico_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.alfabeticBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"amigos_boton_alfabetico_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
[self.alfabeticBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"amigos_boton_alfabetico_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.alfabeticBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(fetchFriends:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

if (self.listType == FriendsListTypeAlfabetic) {
    self.alfabeticBtn.enabled = NO;
}

[self.tableCustomHeader addSubview:self.alfabeticBtn];
[self.tableCustomHeader addSubview:self.rankingBtn];

[self.table setTableHeaderView:self.tableCustomHeader];
```

After that, there is not much else to show. If I return 0 for `numberOfRowsInSection`, I can no longer press the other `UIButton` inside the tableHeaderView to change to the other set of data.

Comment: Two things. 1. Please post some code so we can see what you're talking about. 2. How come you're not using a `UISegmentedControl`?

Comment: Sorry, I did not provide code because I thought It was straightforward, and pretty generic. I'll edit my question. As for not using UISegmentedControl...I'm more familiar customising UIButtons.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the implementation of the selectors theres still no way to figure out whats wrong with the app. Though one problem that looks to be easily solved is the fact that you're always setting the `alfabeticBtn.enabled` to `NO`.

See:

```
if (self.listType == FriendsListTypeRanking) {
    self.alfabeticBtn.enabled = NO;
}

if (self.listType == FriendsListTypeAlfabetic) {
    self.alfabeticBtn.enabled = NO;
}
```

I would fix that and then if you're still having problems update your question with the selector methods.

Comment: Looks like the first one should be `self.rankingBtn`.  Also, they're never set back to `YES`.

Comment: Also correct @AaronBrager he should probably be putting all of that logic into the selector methods.